# Squaring user input Values using POW

Tags: python, math, pow, square-root

Trying to obtain an RMS of a sequence of values from user input, and need to square all the values individually using POW function.

Hello,

I am trying to obtain an RMS of a sequence of values from user input and the first step is that all the values will need to be squared, but I keep getting an error whilst trying to compile the numbers to be squared (using the POW function). I am trying to complete this inside a tkinter GUI.

```
def enter():
    entered_RMS=(entry_RMS.get())                    
    result_RMS = entered_RMS.split(' ')

    # Cast each element as an integer
    for i in range(len(result_RMS)):
        result_RMS[i] = int (result_RMS[i])

    #square each number
    SQR_RMS=pow(result_RMS,2)

    # Add all the elements together
    RMS_total = sum(SQR_RMS)

    #Find the mean by dividing by how many numbers entered
    mean= float (RMS_total/ len (SQR_RMS))

    #Find the mean by dividing by how many numbers entered
    mean= float (RMS_total/ len (SQR_RMS))


    label_RMS.configure(text=str(square)+ ' is the RMS')
```

The error is keep getting is

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

From my understanding, it is due to trying to take use RMS_total as an int and it does not work in the POW function.

Comment: `result_RMS` is a list, you need to apply `pow` to *each value in it*. Look up **list comprehensions**: `SQR_RMS = [pow(int(s), 2) for s in entered_RMS.split(' ')]`

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe that is extremely helpfully!

Comment: pow is not the best way to do it.  Better to square x by writing x*x.

Comment: You can easily write that lambda as x*x instead of pow(x, 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this:

```
import numpy as np
entered_RMS = '1 2 3 4 5'
print(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.array(list(map(float, entered_RMS.split(' '))))**2)))
```

Comment: That is a much cleaner way of doing it did not think to use numpy, thank you

Comment: you're supposed to mark the answer that answers your question